# tensorflow missing dependency declaration for mpi_rendezvous_mgr

Tags: tensorflow, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to compile tensorflow on SL7.3 with verbs and MPI support (no cuda).
I am getting stuck at following error on trying to build using bazel:

Command used for compilation :

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --verbose_failures
```

Error seen:

```
ERROR: /root/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/mpi/BUILD:60:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//tensorflow/contrib/mpi:mpi_rendezvous_mgr':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/contrib/mpi/mpi_rendezvous_mgr.cc':
  '/root/tensorflow/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/tensor_coding.h'.
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
```

Can someone please help me with this ? I tried to look for a solution on stackoverflow (and other forums) but could not find much information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try add a line into ..../tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/mpi/BUILD file

```
...

cc_library(
    name = "mpi_rendezvous_mgr",
    srcs = ["mpi_rendezvous_mgr.cc"],
    hdrs = ["mpi_rendezvous_mgr.h"],
    deps = [
        ":mpi_msg_proto_cc",
        ":mpi_utils",
        "//tensorflow/core:core_cpu_internal",
        "//tensorflow/core:framework",
        "//tensorflow/core:gpu_runtime",
        "//tensorflow/core:lib",
        "//tensorflow/core:protos_cc",
        "//tensorflow/core:worker_proto_cc",
        "//tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime:base_rendezvous_mgr",
        "//tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime:session_mgr",
        "//tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime:worker_env",
        "//third_party/mpi",
        "//tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime:tensor_coding",   ## <<<<< add this line
    ],
)
```

Hope it helps,

BR/thupalo